# Scrape table data with pagination

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, pagination

Trying to scrape the table with Selenium where have pagination. Website which trying to scrape don't have pagination in URL.

```
table = '//*[@id="result-tables"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody'

home = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//tbody/tr/td[5]')
away = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//tbody/tr/td[7]')

teams = []

page = 0
while page < 10:
    page+=1
    time.sleep(5)
    for i in range(len(home)):
        temp_data = home[i].text + '\n' + away[i].text
        pair = teams.append(temp_data)

    next_page = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="result-tables"]/div[3]/ul/li[12]/a/span').click()
```

`teams = []` store only data from the first page. When the script move to another page, get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXX\OneDrive\Documents\A\b\s_pc.py", line 49, in <module>
    temp_data = home[i].text + '\n' + away[i].text
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 76, in text
    return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)['value']
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 693, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 418, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.45)
Stacktrace:
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Maybe you need to define `home` and `away` inside the `while loop` before the `for loop`.

Comment: @pmadhu Just tried to define `home` and `away` inside the `while` but still the same error. Full error message updated.

Comment: If possible share the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have defined the `home` and `away` elements inside the `while loop`. And also shifted the `time.sleep()` at the beginning of the while loop. And the code didnt throw any error.

Check if this is working as expected.

```
table = '//*[@id="result-tables"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody'

teams = []

page = 0
while page < 10:
    time.sleep(5)
    home = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//tbody/tr/td[5]')
    away = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//tbody/tr/td[7]')
    page+=1

    for i in range(len(home)):
        temp_data = home[i].text + '\n' + away[i].text
        pair = teams.append(temp_data)

    next_page = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="result-tables"]/div[3]/ul/li[12]/a/span').click()
```

Comment: Thank you man, it's working. I still can't figure why my code not works when I tried to add inside of the `while`. But its works, thank you again!